# Reading Authentication information from web browser stored in sessions

Tags: javascript, session, browser, session-variables, session-state

**problem scenario :**

I am working on project in which I need to read session variable that web browser uses to keep client login to websites .

**e.g.**

I am sign in on facebook and twitter etc...
when I go to facebook or twitter login page server automatically bring to home by reading session variable stored in my browser or in server again my browser.

**Problem statement:**

what actually I want to do is , get that session variable from web browser and stored then in local file (email and password).

Comment: what you intend to do after you store the session data in local files? Maybe there's better alternative to storing it in file. Normally it's not recommended to mess with authentication cookie issued by server.

Comment: Are you just talking about the session ID that's typically stored in a cookie? If so, that's not going to tell you much and it definitely won't give you emails and passwords

Comment: i need to know how server recognize that browser hand login to their site

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#HTTP_session_token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `Javascript` has no control on session. Its handle by backend language. If you want to use/store Session in any persistency then you need to move up to any backend language like `Java/Python/PHP/Nodejs` etc.

So from webpage client side language you can't access session. It maintains by server. Session management is often managed through the application of [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). Every browser support session management.

Using client side language you can access cookies but you won't found `username/password` in it.

[**Wiki details**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#HTTP_session_token) describes more session management.

---

[**HTTPSession**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is interface used for storing and getting session in java.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("object", object);
```

Answer (score 0):

So the way websites usually (though not always) handle login credentials in this scenario is like so.

1. I go to the website and login
2. If my credentials validate the server assigns my browser a cookie with a token in it that maps to a value on my server/database
3. When a request comes in I check that cookie value and if it has a valid token render out the appropriate content matched up to that user.

This can change depending on what platform you are on and if there are built in mechanisms for doing this.